# What is wrong with my general solution and how to find $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Given that $$y=\frac{1}{w}$$

[image]

---

Here is my working:

$$\frac{d^2w}{dx^2}+2\frac{dw}{dx}+5w=-5x^2-4x-2$$

**Auxillary Equation:** $$a^2+2a+5=0$$

$$a=-1+2i,-1-2i$$

---

**C.F**

$$w=e^{-x}(C \cos 2x+ E \sin 2x)$$

---

**P.I**

$$w=Ax^2+Bx+D$$

$$w'=2Ax+B$$

$$w''=2A$$

Substituting to equation:

$$2A+4Ax+2B+5Ax^2+5Bx+5D=-5x^2-4x-2$$

Equating coefficients:

$$5A=-5 \implies A=-1$$

$$4A+5B=-4 \implies B=0$$

$$2A+2B+5D=-2 \implies D=0$$

---

Therefore General solution:

$$w=e^{-x}(C \cos 2x+ E \sin 2x)-x^2$$

However my book says :

$$w=e^{-x}(C \cos 2x+ E \sin 2x)$$

What did I do wrong? Please help

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,  your book gave only the solution to the homogeneous equation.  You can see that plugging that into the equation will give you 0, so it CAN'T give you the right hand side.   What's more,  you can check to see if your particular solution works.

So, your particular solution is $w=-x^2$.  hence $w'=-2x$,$w''=-2$

Plugging those into $w''+2w'+5w$,  we se we get $-2+2(-2x)+5(-x^2)$  Rewriting this, we get

$-5x^2-4x-2$, which is the right hand side, hence your particular solution is good.

For your asymptope, you're looking for a function that goes to infinity at the same rate as $\frac 1 w$. for ease of notation, I'm going to move $f^{-1}(x)$ to the numerator and solve for that, as it's a bit more natural

$\frac {f^{-1}(x)} {e^{-x}(C\cos 2x +E\sin 2x)-x^2}$.
Exponential completely overpowers polynomial, and the cosine and sine are just sinusoidals.   I have to run to teach my class now, but if you still need help later tonight, I'll come back to see about finishing this.  It's weird with the asymptope being for $\frac 1 w$ instead of $w$ thoubh

Comment: (+1) "Asymptote" ? Ummmm no idea still how to find $f(x)$ :/

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming that Im correct :)

Comment: Alan :) Can you please please tell me how you found $f(x)$ at the limit :)